# In Java 8, how do I convert a List of "flat" objects into a List of nested objects?

Tags: java, java-8, nested, java-stream, collectors

I'm using Java 8.  I have a java.util.List of these "MyFlatObject" objects ...

```
public class MyFlatObject {
    private String category;
    private String productId;
    private String feature;
    ...
}
```

How would I convert this List into another List of Category objects, in which those are defined as

```
public class Category {
    private String category;
    private List<Product> products;
    ...
}

public class Product {
    private String productId;
    private List<String> features;
    ...
}
```

?  The goal being that if the List<MyFlatObject> list has 12 objects, but only 3 distinct categories, my resulting List<Category> list would only have three objects, each with the distinct Category object and within each Category object, all the relevant products.

Comment: I wanted to see if, with Java 8's streams and Collectors functionality, there was a slicker, shorter way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

What you are possibly looking for would be `Collectors.groupingBy` with a downstream function using `Collectors.mapping`. If I get it right you are looking to group by multiple attributes and transform them into new objects which is where `Collectors.collectingAndThen` could be handy.

Assuming few getters and constructors over these classes, the approach could be similar to:

```
List<Category> categories = flatObjects.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.groupingBy(MyFlatObject::getCategory,
                        Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                                Collectors.groupingBy(MyFlatObject::getProductId,
                                        Collectors.mapping(MyFlatObject::getFeature, Collectors.toList())),
                                val -> val.entrySet()
                                        .stream()
                                        .map(e -> new Product(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
                                        .toList())),
                val -> val.entrySet().stream()
                        .map(e -> new Category(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
                        .toList())
        );
```

Comment: ".toList()" doesn't seem to compile, but even when I substitute ".collect(Collectors.toList())", I don't seem to be getting the correct results.

Comment: @Dave I have shared an approach to solving the problem, but given there is not much clarity on the sample where you want to execute it and the expected output, I would not further be able to add the details. If there is any sort of exception that you get, feel free to follow up with more details.